# Weird IE bug - Wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I am having problems with a weird IE bug and cant figure out why its upset. I am testing it in IE 11.

The problem is that one section of my page wont appear on IE, but it appears fine on Firefox and Chrome. The code is written so that there is a Desktop and Mobile/tablet version of the section and they run 100% fine in Chrome and Firefox, yet IE just wont display anything.

This is the page and if you scroll down to "Vi hjælpe i alle fag" you will see the problem.
http://u1f8aki.nixweb23.dandomain.dk/folkeskolen/

Any suggestions as to what is wrong or how i can fix it are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: display flex isn't fully supported on IE since it has a lot of bugs

Comment: IE 11 requires a unit to be added to the third argument, the flex-basis property

Comment: In IE10 and IE11, containers with display: flex and flex-direction: column will not properly calculate their flexed childrens' sizes if the container has min-height but no explicit height property.

Comment: IE 11 does not vertically align items correctly when min-height is used

Comment: In IE10 the default value for flex is 0 0 auto rather than 0 1 auto as defined in the latest spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style in your style.css

```
.subjects {   
   width: 100%;
}
```